# Configuration and positionning of beacons for indoor navigation

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I'm using ibks beacons for an indoor navigation application and my problem is that the area where I have to place my beacons is filled with metalic items, so the signal is very imprecise. How can I get a better signal ? By configuring beacons or by placing them in a precise way ?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick things you can do:

- turn the transmit power all the way up on your beacons. This will result in more accurate distance estimates
- increase the transmit frequency of your beacons, so you have more data points to average over.
- put more beacons in the space
- put your beacons up higher - depending on your space and the objects causing interference, this often helps.

Even with all of the above, trilateration is not likely to work very well, but depending on your accuracy requirements you may get something that works well enough.